# Why do I keep getting an Out-Of-Memory error with Redux-Persist?

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-redux, v8, redux-persist

Occasionally when rebooting my app, my emulator throws this error

[image: O]

Accompanied by this stacktrace

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: v8::String::WriteUtf8(char*, int, int*, int) const [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: node::StringBytes::Write(v8::Isolate*, char*, unsigned long, v8::Local<v8::Value>, node::encoding, int*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: int node::StreamBase::WriteString<(node::encoding)1>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: void node::StreamBase::JSMethod<node::LibuvStreamWrap, &(int node::StreamBase::WriteString<(node::encoding)1>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x2672e7c842fd
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:868:14)
/Users/jisata0/Dev/exampleapp/node_modules/react-native/scripts/packager.sh: line 11: 86698 Abort trap: 6           node "./local-cli/cli.js" start "$@"
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

Can anyone provide some clarity on why this might be happening?

Comment: Please do not post images of errors. Post the error text itself. Images are not searchable, and will lead to duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

A client is required to review the basic application response to performance improvements. One of the most common causes of performance problems is memory leak.

Out of memory is an error that occurs when the limit of available memory is exceeded.

The simplest way to apply it is to have more memory available to the app.

You can use Add to `android / app / src / main / AndroidManifest.xml`.

```xml
<application android:largeHeap="true"
```

If you still have out of memory, try debugging any code you've written that uses more memory than you intended or creates a memory lock.